# "t-Chart" value

Tags: regression, self-study, t-distribution

I wonder what is wrong with my own answer for the problem which I have shared below, could you please help me some about that:

" Suppose that we have 12 observation units $ ( n=12 ) $ in a statistical investigation. What is the "t-table" value $ ( {\downarrow}v^{ \backslash ^{\large{p} \, \rightarrow} } \;  )  $ for $ \, t_{0,01} $ ? "

And, I thought, it would be better to add also [a link for a sample of "t-chart"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution#Table_of_selected_values)

I have tried to find the solution $ (v=n-2=10 \; \land \; t_{0,01}= 3,169 ) $ but, it did not work for me so far because, the answer key for this problem shows $ ' 3,106 ' $ instead of $ ' 3,169 '  $ I am just guessing that there might be something wrong with the answer key, so what do you think in order to get a correct solution for this problem? Please, show me how to do that.

Thank you very much.

Comment: What is the basis for using $n-2$ for the degrees of freedom?  (It could be valid, but we need more information to know.)

Comment: Well, since I have been studying Statics for a very short period, I can not tell to much but, I have known these versions:
1)- v= n-2,
2)- v= n-1,
3)- v= (current column * current row) / total cell ...
Actually, I have not very much idea what it is used for. I mean "degrees of freedom" ...

Comment: If it is a one sample problem the degrees of freedom is n-1 where n is the sample size.  If it is the difference of two independent sample means it is n1+n2-2 where n1 is the sample size from the first population and n2 is the sample size from the second population if you let n=n1+n2 the total sample size then you have n-2 in the two sample case.  So I take it that when you look up the percentage point for t with 11 degrees of freedom you get 3.106.

Comment: I think bill may have guessed right off the bat that the degrees of freedom was wrong since the critical value goes down as the degrees of freedom increases.

Comment: Thanks @Michael.  I didn't guess: I merely consulted the table provided in the question!

Comment: Okay but as clever as you are, like me you could have guessed that that was the problem without even consulting the table.  I still haven't looked it up but I trsut Harvey on his confirmation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whoever created the answer key must have assumed that df equals n-1. That would make sense, if the statistical test was a one-sample t test. Without specifying the context, the question is ambiguous. It is also essential to specify if the 0.01 probability is one- or two-tails.

With 11 degrees of freedom, and assuming the 0.01 refers to a two-tail P value,  the critical t is indeed 3.106. ([One online calculator](http://www.graphpad.com/quickcalcs/Statratio1.cfm).)

Comment: Thank you very much...and, sorry for a late reply for your answer... :) I will recheck everything again...